# Requests/urllib not working in Flask/Apache/mod_wsgi/Windows

Tags: python, apache, flask, python-requests, mod-wsgi

I have a Flask app with code that processes data coming from a request to another web app hosted on a different server, and it works just fine in development, furthermore, the library that processes the request can be called and used perfectly fine from python in our Windows server... However when the library is called by the webapp in production using mod_wsgi it refuses to work, requests made by the server just... time out.

I have tried everything from moving my code to the file it's used in, to switching from requests to urllib... nothing, so long as they're made from mod_wsgi all requests I make time out.
Why is that? is it some weird apache configuration thing that I'm unaware of?

I'm posting the library below (sorry I have to censor it up a bit, but I promise it *works*)

```
import requests
import re


class CannotAccessServerException(Exception):
    pass

class ServerItemNotFoundException(Exception):
    pass


class Service():
    REQUEST_URL = "http://server-ip/url?query={query}&toexcel=csv"

    @classmethod
    def fetch_info(cls, query):
        # Get Approximate matches
        try:
            server_request = requests.get(cls.REQUEST_URL.format(query = query), timeout = 30).content
        except:
            raise CannotAccessServerException

        # If you're getting ServerItemNotFoundException or funny values consistently maybe the server has changed their tables.
        server_regex = re.compile('^([\d\-]+);[\d\-]+;[\d\-]+;[\d\-]+;[\d\-]+;[\-"\w]+;[\w"\-]+;{query};[\w"\-]+;[\w"\-]+;[\w"\-]+;[\w"\-]+;[\w\s:"\-]+;[\w\s"\-]+;[\d\-]+;[\d\-]+;[\d\-]+;([\w\-]+);[\w\s"\-]+;[\w\-]+;[\w\s"\-]+;[\d\-]+;[\d\-]+;[\d\-]+;([\w\-]+);[\d\-]+;[\d\-]+;[\w\-]+;[\w\-]+;[\w\-]+;[\w\-]+;[\w\s"\-]+$'.format(query = query), re.MULTILINE)

        server_exact_match = server_regex.search(server_request.decode())

        if server_exact_match is None:
            raise ServerItemNotFoundException


        result_json = {
            "retrieved1": server_exact_match.group(1),
            "retrieved2": server_exact_match.group(2),
            "retrieved3": server_exact_match.group(3)
        }

        return result_json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Service.fetch_info(99999))
```

PS: I know it times out because one of the things I tried was capturing the error raised by requests.get and returning its *repr* esentation.

Comment: My first guess would be a firewall blocking outbound connections from the production server. If it's on Windows, it's even more possible that the restrictions apply to the Apache process but not to a script run separately?

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody's wondering, after lots of research, trying to run my module as a subprocess, and all kinds of experiments, I had to resort to replicating the entirety of the dataset I needed to query from the remote server to my database with a weekly crontab task and then querying that.

So... Yeah, I don't have a solution, to be frank, or an explanation of why this happens. But if this is happening to you, your best bet might sadly be replicating the entire dataset on your server.